# getting wrong sum in sql while using cases

Tags: sql, sql-server

- im getting incorrect data in sql out put
- it should come 2 improves , but its always adding 1 decrease count even though there is no cause for becoming decrease count
- im counting from 1st query output and counting from another query to    display

query

```
SELECT USERNAME,
       Sum(IMPROVED)  IMPROVED,
       Sum(DECREASED) DECREASED
FROM   (SELECT ( k.keyword ),
               p.projectname,
               pa.username,
               CASE
                 WHEN a.currentposition > b.currentposition THEN 1
               END               IMPROVED,
               CASE
                 WHEN b.currentposition > a.currentposition THEN 1
               END               DECREASED,
               a.currentposition AS oldposition,
               b.currentposition AS newposition
        FROM   seo.tbl_keywordposition b
               JOIN seo.tbl_keywordposition a
                 ON a.keywordid = b.keywordid
                    AND a.psnupdatedate = '1/22/2015'
                    AND b.psnupdatedate = '1/23/2015'
               LEFT JOIN tbl_keywords k
                      ON k.keywordid = b.keywordid
                         AND a.keywordid = b.keywordid
               LEFT JOIN tbl_project p
                      ON p.ProjectId = k.ProjId
               LEFT JOIN tbl_projAssignment pa
                      ON pa.ProjId = p.ProjectId
                         AND pa.KeywordID = k.keywordid
        WHERE  p.Projectname = 'krishnaproject1')INNERQUERY
GROUP  BY USERNAME
```

screen shot of my error. kindly see this link 
http://postimg.org/image/d8s6rsgvt/

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/d8s6rsgvt/

Comment: i cant post here due to less reputations..kindly see my link for screen shot

Comment: i was wriiten like that only to post u query i just removed else 0

Comment: no effect from else 0 , always decrease getting added 1

Comment: In first set of join `tbl_keywordposition b` has a later date `1/23/2015` and `tbl_keywordposition a` has date `'1/22/2015'`. Say on `'1/22/2015'` currentposition or `oldposition` is 1 and on `1/23/2015` `newposition` is 0. Then based on first case condition `a.currentposition(oldposition)` is greater than `b.currentposition (newposition)` and so count 1 will be added in `IMPROVED`.Are you sure this logic is correct? it's looking as if you are expecting the opposite..

Comment: yes , im working on seo. so keyword positions should decrease to improve.

Comment: Ok post some sample data to help you better .. from all the 4 tables

Comment: query works well , only for first time,its giving decrease even though it is improve..after 1st record calculation ,,its again giving right calculation..for first time record counting if only one record present then its decreasing

Comment: is it like you can have multiple records on a single `psnupdatedate` and you want to consider only the latest one for performance calculation? If yes then how you decide which is the latest record in `tbl_keywordposition` Is thr an Id feild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your case statement to set the else value to be 0 because when you dont set it to anything it assigns the value to it as `NULL` and  What is the sum of null and a number, exactly? Note where the 1 comes from: the only row which has non-null Column1 and Column2.

```
           CASE
             WHEN a.currentposition > b.currentposition THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END IMPROVED,
           CASE
             WHEN b.currentposition > a.currentposition THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END  DECREASED,
```

Or you can also use the `COALESCE` in your outer select

```
         SELECT USERNAME,
               Sum(COALESCE(IMPROVED,0))  IMPROVED,
               Sum(COALESCE(DECREASED,0)) DECREASED
```

Answer (score 0):

group USERNAME inside your sub-query.

```
WHERE  p.Projectname = 'krishnaproject1' GROUP  BY USERNAME )INNERQUERY
```